# GAE project Intellij remote debug doesn't release port when shutdown

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, jetty, intellij-14

I'm building the "Hello World" Google App Engine application on Intellij. The code builds and runs fine on GAE. I tried to run and debug it locally in Intellij by following this page: https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-local
(NOTE: I'm using community addition and following the instruction for community edition as well)

Every time I debug a server, it runs fine, shows up in localhost:PORT_NUMBER fine. However, when I click "stop debug" (the red square you usually click to end a debug program) and rerun it, I get this:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: Could not open the requested socket: Address already in use
[INFO] GCLOUD: Try overriding --address and/or --port.
```

Apparently every time I start the server and shut it down, the port is not released normally. I tried changing the port number a couple of times, and each time the server starts fine on first run and cannot obtain port number afterwards.

Note that after stopping the server, localhost:PORT_NUMBER no longer shows the hello world string. Instead it shows

```
HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /. Reason:

NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://
```

instead of the usual "This site can’t be reached" message for an non-existent port.

```
$ netstat -na | grep ':81'
tcp6       0      0 :::8176                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8177                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8178                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8179                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8180                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8181                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the team that builds this plugin.

Are you using Maven and the `app-maven-plugin`?

What you encountered, I think, is a bug in the documentation. Instead of using the following command in the Maven run configuration:

```
appengine:start
```

Try using:

```
appengine:run
```

The former runs the dev server asynchronously which explains why its not being killed when you hit the stop button.

To start over (if you are on OSX) you can run the following commands to find and kill the runaway process:

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep [replace with your port #]
```

then:

```
kill -9 [process id found via the previous command]
```

Thanks for reporting and I'll make sure to get the documentation updated.

Comment: FWIW I figured out a solution that *sort of* works. Instead of following the instruction on that page (setting up remote debug and everything) I just need two maven config, appengine:start and appengine:stop. Running one starts the server and the other shuts it down cleanly. appengine:run doesn't make a big difference, terminating the process still leaves the server running, but calling appengine:stop shuts it down.

Comment: The reason I say it *sort of* works is if by mistake I appengine:start again before I remember to appengine:stop, the server gets into some kind of error, not working properly any more but calling appengine:stop no longer works. So essentially I get a zombie state server and have to use another port or clean up the port before starting the server again.

Comment: I think that if you use appengine:run, then pressing the stop button will kill the command automatically (since the run configurations are chained). is this not what you experienced (in my testing, it correctly terminated the dev server)? (also - to be safe since I made this mistake - execute the remote debug configuration, not the maven configuration)

Comment: Just an update that we've updated the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-local#community) here to point to the `appengine:run` command instead.